# React make table with JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I have an API endpoint which returns me Google Sheets data like that:

```js
[{'App Id': '1', 'Name': 'Test', 'Homepage': 'example.com'}, {'App Id': '2', 'Name': 'Another', 'Homepage': 'example.org'}]
```

I'm fetching the data above with `axios`, using the following code.

```js
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1/')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

And I want to make an table with that data in React. The table should look like that:

```
| App Id | Name    | Homepage    |
|--------|---------|-------------|
| 1      | Test    | example.com |
| 2      | Another | example.org |
```

How can I render this data to look like table above?

Comment: Please be mindful that questions on the opinions are no longer allowed anywhere on the network, this is not the place for opinion polls or subjective discussion type questions

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Sorry, editing my question now.

Comment: @g14u you want a normal table like this with the data that you get https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp, if thats the case will add the answer

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS No, data that fetched from the REST API should be added to the table. Which is `[{'App Id': '1', 'Name': 'Test', 'Homepage': 'example.com'}, {'App Id': '2', 'Name': 'Another', 'Homepage': 'example.org'}]`

Comment: Since the api is not exposed i will add a sample same kind of answer kindly check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as discussed you need to build the table with the data that you get from the rest api

here you can have the columns as static

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const columns = [
    { property: "id", header: "Id" },
    { property: "title", header: "Title" }
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      const response = await axios(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"
      );
      setData(response.data);
    };
    loadData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <table>
        <tr>
          {columns.map(col => (
            <th>{col.header}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
        {data.map(datumn => {
          return (
            <tr>
              {columns.map(col => {
                return <td>{datumn[col.property]}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

**styles.css**

```
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Sample [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-with-rest-api-data-elwnc)

you can improvise by adding the error and loading state.

Answer (score -1):

There could be several ways to implement what you require.

It can be implemented using plain html, and bootstrap the design according to your own convenience.

You would have to set the data in your state and map it when its being rendered.

[Link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/table/)

Above link will take you to the documentation of bootstrap where you can find the code snippets related to table.